# Xcode 7 UI Testing: Dismiss Push and Location alerts

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I encountered a problem with Xcode 7 UI Testing.

The app displays two alerts after my user logs in, the **Request Location** Alert and the **Push Notifications** Alert. Those notifications are shown one right after the other. The Location one appears first.

I try to dismiss them automatically to start my tests.

In order to do that, I add two *UIInterruptionMonitor*, the first one for the Location Alert and the second one for the Notification Push Alert.

```
    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
        /* Dismiss Location Dialog */
        if alert.collectionViews.buttons["Allow"].exists {
            alert.collectionViews.buttons["Allow"].tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Push Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
        /* Dismiss Push Dialog */
        if alert.collectionViews.buttons["OK"].exists {
            alert.collectionViews.buttons["OK"].tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

But only the Location one is triggered, the handler of Push Notifications *UIInterruptionMonitor* is never called.

If I return true in the **Request Location** *UIInterruptionMonitor* as [this other post accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148965/xcode-7-ui-testing-how-to-dismiss-a-series-of-system-alerts-in-code) specifies. Both handler are called but the *alert* parameter in both *UIInterruptionMonitor* links to the **Request Location** Alert View so the "OK" button is never found.

How can I dismiss those two successive alerts views?

Comment: I'm dealing with the exact same issue, but haven't found a solution yet. I tried using only one and checking for "Allow" and "OK" in both, but that didn't work either....

Comment: I have been wrestling this exact issue for days now. Do you have any progress? SO frustrating

Comment: I'm stuck with this problem also. A single alert? No Problem. Two successive alerts => Only 1 is tapped.

Answer (score 11):

While not ideal, I found that if you simply wait until one authorization dialog has finished before presenting another one in the app, UI tests can pick up multiple requests in a row.

```
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways {
        self.locationManager.requestLocation()
    } else {
        self.contactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) { _ in
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
```

I'm actually requesting access to contacts in a different place in my code, but it can handle multiple simultaneous requests just fine.

Then in my test:

```
    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
        let button = alert.buttons["Allow"]
        if button.exists {
            button.tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Contacts Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
        let button = alert.buttons["OK"]
        if button.exists {
            button.tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    app.buttons["Location"].tap()

    app.tap() // need to interact with the app for the handler to fire
    app.tap() // need to interact with the app for the handler to fire
```

Answer (score 3):

As I noted in [the answer you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32228033/384110), you must interact with the application after the alert appears.

> Second, after presenting the alert you must interact with the interface. Simply tapping the app works just fine, but is required.

```
// add UI interruption handlers

app.buttons["Request Location"].tap()
app.tap() // need to interact with the app for the handler to fire
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said, without success. To solve my problem, I had to delay one of the two alerts.

Comment: Great! If this is working for you please accept the answer so others know that it should work for them.

Comment: How did you add a delay?

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseTest: XCTestCase {
    let pushSent = NSNotification.Name.init("alert.pushSent")
    var notificationMonitor: NSObjectProtocol?

    override func setUp() {
        listenNotifications()
        let app = XCUIApplication()

        notificationMonitor = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Push Notifications") { [unowned self] (alert) -> Bool in
            let btnAllow = app.buttons["Allow"]
            //1:
            if btnAllow.exists {
                btnAllow.tap()
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.pushSent, object: nil)
                return true
            }
            //2:
            //takeScreenshot
            XCTFail("Unexpected System Alert")
            return false
        }
        //3:
        //add code for "Request Location" monitor

        app.launchEnvironment = ["UITEST_DISABLE_ANIMATIONS" : "YES"]
        //4:
        app.launch()

    }

    func listenNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: pushSent, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            if let locationDialogHandeler = self.notificationMonitor {
                //5:
                self.removeUIInterruptionMonitor(locationDialogHandeler)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1: Check if you're in the correct alert, tap the button and find a way to remove the monitor (I'm using NotificationCenter)

2: If you enter a monitor and can not find the right button, it means it's an unexpected flow. Fail the test (but take a screenshot first).

3: Add other monitors

4: I am adding monitor even before launching the app. If you add a monitor after the alert appears, it will not be triggered.

**5: Remove the monitor, that way when a new alert appears, the next monitor in the stack will be called.**

P.S: You should add monitors in reverse order, therefore, add "Request Location" after "Push Notifications"

Answer (score -1):

To dismiss system alert views (ie: **Push Notification**) you can [define custom flags for the testing environment](https://github.com/nathankot/NKMultipeer/wiki/How-to-define-custom-flags-for-the-testing-environment).

Then, you just have to change the application's code to avoid specific initialisations (ie: **Push Notification**) :

```
#if !TESTING
let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
#endif
```

I use this trick in order to be able to take screenshots with [snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, only disables one of the capabilities in the app.

Comment: The question was : "How can I dismiss those two successive alerts views?"