# Dismissing multiple alerts XCUITesing

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am am writing my XCUITests for my app, and currently struggling in finding the best solutions to dismiss my apps alerts. I have two sets of alerts, one is a `notifications` alert which pops up at the beginning of a fresh install, the second is a `location` alert when I navigate to the nearby tab on my app after a fresh install. I have tried using

```
let alert = app.alerts["\u{201c}VoucherCodes\u{201d} Would Like to Send You Notifcations"].collectionViews.buttons["OK"]
    if alert.exists{
        alert.tap()
    }
```

but no success, I have also tried using a `systemAlertMonitorToken`in my my `setUp()`

```
   systemAlertMonitorToken = addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription(systemAlertHandlerDescription) { (alert) -> Bool in
        if alert.buttons.matchingIdentifier("OK").count > 0 {
            alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or point out where I am going wrong so I can fix this, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 UI Testing: how to dismiss a series of system alerts in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148965/xcode-7-ui-testing-how-to-dismiss-a-series-of-system-alerts-in-code)

Comment: This question seems to be asking how to dismiss multiple alerts, or an alert that may or may not be presented depending on previous settings, not just how to dismiss an alert.

Answer (score 0):

You might find these two questions and their answers to be illuminating:

[Xcode 7 UI Testing: Dismiss Push and Location alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875301/xcode-7-ui-testing-dismiss-push-and-location-alerts)

[Xcode 7 UI Testing: how to dismiss a series of system alerts in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148965/xcode-7-ui-testing-how-to-dismiss-a-series-of-system-alerts-in-code)