# Clearing an SFAuthenticationSession alert in an XCUITest with addUIInterruptionMonitor()

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, sfauthenticationsession

Has anybody successfully used `addUIInterruptionMonitor` to clear the alert produced by `start()`ing an `SFAuthenticationSession` while running an XCUITest?

I can't get it to work on Xcode 9.1/iOS 11.1.1 (simulator or device). The [standard advice](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-interact-with-a-system-alert) (setting up the handler and subsequently interacting with the device before the alert appears) does not help.

The test recorder says `app.alerts.firstMatch.buttons["Continue"]).tap()` should do the trick, but that doesn't work either. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46951214) technique from another SO answer works *sometimes*, but not consistently on CI.

So I'd like to know if the "official" solution has ever worked for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work:

```
let continueButton = app.alerts.buttons["Continue"]
XCTAssert(waitAndTap(continueButton), "could not tap on alert \"Continue\" button"
```

But this hack seems to do the trick:

```
let statusBarsQuery = app.statusBars
statusBarsQuery.element.tap()
```