# XCUItest addUIInterruptionMonitor is not capturing alerts on iOS14 simulator and xcode 12

Tags: alert, ios14, xcuitest

```
override func setUp() {
    addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "App store alert") { (alert) -> Bool in
        alert.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
        return true
         }
}


func test() {
    functionThatCausesAlertToAppear()
    XCUIApplication().tap()
}
```

When I attempt to print a statement within the addUIInterruptionMonitor it doesn't print leading me to believe that the block isn't triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not solve the issue at hand I've found a workaround from: [addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription:handler:) not working on iOS 10 or 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228343/adduiinterruptionmonitorwithdescriptionhandler-not-working-on-ios-10-or-9)

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard") 

let allowBtn = springboard.buttons["Allow"]
if allowBtn.waitForExistence(timeout: 10) {
    allowBtn.tap()
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem using Xcode 12.4 and an actual phone running iOS 14.5 beta  as well.  I used the same workaround and it works for some alerts, but doesn't work when the phone receives a full screen phone call. It does detect if the phone calls are set to banner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into the issue where your interruption is not firing even after making sure the code is correct, then read this documentation on Apple website - [Handling UI Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/handling_ui_interruptions).

I too faced this challenge, and after realizing the issue, i simply identified the ***OK*** button and tapped on it in the flow.

Hope this helps in your case too!