# How to wait for UI element without failing test case

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a dialog that displays on first execution of my app. I therefore want my test case to handle responding to the dialog - but only if it appears.

The waitForExpectations method will error out if the timeout is reached.

What is the best way to wait for this element to appear for a short time without failing the test case if it does not appear?

Comment: If the dialog only appears when the app is first executed, why not use the testing logic only on the first execution of the app too?

Comment: How can I know it is the first execution of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reimplement waiting. As terrible as it sounds, I recommend using Sleep and If statements; you want to lock your test thread while it waits for the app to finish presenting content, then evaluate.

Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware none of the options for `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` permit you to not fail the test if the expectationForPredicate is not fulfilled at the end of the timeout time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("SYSTEM_DESCRIPTION") { (alert) -> Bool in
  alert.buttons["BUTTON_TITLE"].tap()
  return true
}

app.buttons["BUTTON_TITLE"].tap()
app.tap()
```

SYSTEM_DESCRIPTION is the title or description of system alert.

BUTTON_TITLE is like "OK", "Allow", ...

Find out more in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32228033/6657951