# Swift Error "Variable used within its own initial value"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing my XCUITest's for my app. 
I am declaring the alert in order to use `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` to make my test asynchronous....However it is throwing the error `Variable used within its own initial value` on the declaration of `alert` on line 5.

```
    let timeout = NSTimeInterval()
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
    let alert = alert.buttons["OK"]


    testCase.addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Enable Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in
            alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
        return true
    }

    self.buttons["Enable notifications"].tap()
    testCase.expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: alert, handler: nil)
    testCase.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout, handler: nil)
    app.tap()
```

Can someone tell me why it is throwing this error and what I can do to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because in your line no. 5, you have written

```
let alert = alert.buttons["OK"]
```

alert was never declared before this line, so you cannot write this.

For example, take this case,

```
let a = a+5
```

Now compiler will throw the same error as it does not know the value of 'a' as it was not declared before.

Comment: Okay, so how must I declare alert before?

Comment: I am not familiar with Xcode Tests, just answered for the your question. Found this on the internet after searching a bit - let alert = app.alerts.elementBoundByIndex(0).buttons["OK"] - try once

Comment: If not helpful try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148965/xcode-7-ui-testing-how-to-dismiss-a-series-of-system-alerts-in-code or wait someone having knowledge on this to answer