# addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode-ui-testing

In my UI tests I'm using the `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` method as pointed in various places ([1](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/129-more-ui-testing-tips), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33875301/657676), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33505420/657676)), as below:

```
var systemAlertMonitorToken: NSObjectProtocol?

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    SDStatusBarManager.sharedInstance().enableOverrides()

    continueAfterFailure = false

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    setupSnapshot(app)
    app.launchEnvironment["UITests"] = "true"

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .LandscapeLeft
    } else {
        XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .Portrait
    }

    app.launch()

    systemAlertMonitorToken = addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Photos Permission Alert") { (alert) -> Bool in
        if alert.buttons.matchingIdentifier("OK").count > 0 {
            alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
            // Required to return focus to app
            app.tap()
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

override func tearDown() {
    if let systemAlertMonitorToken = systemAlertMonitorToken {
        removeUIInterruptionMonitor(systemAlertMonitorToken)
    }

    super.tearDown()
}

func testSomethingWithPhotos() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    // This will trigger the photos permission alert
    app.tabBars.buttons["Scan"].tap()

    // ... further tests
}
```

This functions are expected (the ""App Name" Would Like to Access Your Photos" alert is dismissed) on iPhones, but when run on an iPad, the alert is displayed but it is not dismissed, and if I place a breakpoint in the callback it is never triggered. Is there a way to have this function on iPads?

I have also tried:
 - Placing the `app.tap()` call in the `testSomethingWithPhotos` function after the `app.tabBars.buttons["Scan"].tap()` line, but no luck.
 - Putting the call to `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` before the `super.setup()` call.
 - Putting the call to `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` in the `testSomethingWithPhotos` function, before the line that would trigger the alert