# UI Test - System Alert in Landscape mode

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am working on UI Test for several System Alerts in a row (ie. a video app to get permission for Camera, Microphone and Photos). With a sample project, it seems the new method `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` is not working for Landscape mode.

I come across this post [Swift UI Test - User Notifications System Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203730/swift-ui-test-user-notifications-system-alert), but the case is different for me.

My code looks like this:

```
    let desc = "\u{201c}Alert\u{201d} Would Like to Access the Camera"

    let app = XCUIApplication()

    addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription(desc) { (alert) -> Bool in
        let okButton = alert.buttons["OK"]
        print(okButton.frame)
        okButton.tap()
        return true
    }
    app.buttons["Alert"].tap()
```

It works for Portrait, not Landscape. The case can be reproduced by Simulator and Device.

Moreover the `okButton.frame` I got in Portrait is

```
 CGRect
  ▿ origin : CGPoint
    - x : 207.0
    - y : 387.666666666667
  ▿ size : CGSize
    - width : 135.0
    - height : 44.0
```

but the frame in Landscape shows like this

[image: Landscape System Alert]

```
 CGRect
  ▿ origin : CGPoint
    - x : 143.333333333333
    - y : 368.0
  ▿ size : CGSize
    - width : 44.0
    - height : 135.0
```

The test failure error I got is this one

> test failure: -[AlertUITests testExample()] failed: UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button 0x14df73840: traits: 8589934593, {{277.0, 345.0}, {46.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Button', error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003

Any idea?

**EDIT 1**

Submitted to Radar rdar://23931990

Comment: This is the exact problem of the question you references. Check out the asker's edits, they mention the app being in landscape mode as well.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I noticed the edit. However, it is a different problem. As mentioned by the asker, his app taps on the `Dont Allow` button, while in my case, it shows error with AX action.

Comment: Sounds like there's a bug with landscape system alerts, right? I think a radr is all we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a framework bug.

Try use something like this:

Helpers:

```
var device: XCUIDevice {return XCUIDevice.shared()}

extension XCUIDevice {

    func type() -> String {

        if XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).horizontalSizeClass == .compact || XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).verticalSizeClass == .compact {

            return "iPhone"

        } else {

            return "iPad"
        }
    }
}
```

Method:

```
func handleOrientation(_ orientationAltered: Bool) -> Bool {

        guard device.type() == "iPad" else {return false}

        if !orientationAltered && device.orientation == .landscapeLeft {

            device.orientation = .portrait
            return true

        } else if orientationAltered && (device.orientation == .landscapeLeft || device.orientation == .landscapeRight) {

            device.orientation = .landscapeLeft
            return false

        } else {return false}
    }
```